# buttons added to table won't fire handler

Tags: javascript, button, event-handling

In my table, I'm trying to include an Edit button at the end of each row. The idea is for the user to click one of these to alter the row's content. I can build and populate the table just fine, but I cannot get the buttons to fire off their handler.

Here's a code snippet:

```
window.onload = function (){
  // a bunch of stuff happens correctly...

  while (!Rs.EOF)
  {
    var oRow = oTicketsTable.insertRow();

    for (j=0; j < field.length; j++)
    {
      var oCell = oRow.insertCell();

      oCell.style.fontSize = "10";
      oCell.style.fontWeight = "normal";
      oCell.style.border = "thin black solid";
      oCell.innerText = Rs(field[j]);
    }

    var oCell = oRow.insertCell();
    oCell.style.border = "thin black solid";

    var oBtn = document.createElement("button");
    oCell.appendChild(oBtn);

    oBtn.innerHTML = Rs('idnum');
    oBtn.onClick = function () { alert("oBtn.onClick"); }

    Rs.MoveNext();
  }

  Rs.Close ();
  delete Rs;

  var btn = document.createElement("button");
  btn.style.height = "50px";
  btn.style.width = "150px";
  document.body.appendChild(btn);

  btn.innerHTML="button1";
  btn.onclick = function() { alert("button1 calling"); 
}
```

The code at the end creates a test button which fires off just fine. But none of the buttons in the table work.

Answer (score 0):

The onclick function in the table is camel case: try changing it to lower case? Change **obtn.onClick** to **obtn.onclick**.

```
oBtn.onclick = function () { alert("oBtn.onClick"); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
oBtn.onclick = function () { alert("oBtn.onClick"); }

Rs.MoveNext();
}
```

Instead of:

```
oBtn.onClick = function () { alert("oBtn.onClick"); }

Rs.MoveNext();
}
```

capitalized 'C', should be just 'c'

Answer (score 0):

If I not mistaken, you should place your event outside, as global.

```
var oBtn,btn;
window.onload = function (){

    // other code

    // other code

    oBtn = document.createElement("button");
    oBtn.innerHTML = Rs('idnum');


    btn = document.createElement("button");
    btn.style.height = "50px";
    btn.style.width = "150px";
    document.body.appendChild(btn);

    btn.innerHTML="button1";

}

// make your event global
oBtn.onClick = function () { alert("oBtn.onClick"); }
btn.onclick = function() { alert("button1 calling"); }
```

`.onClick` is an old practice. But I think it would just prompt you a warning, not an error.